# Filter through objects and get field value

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have the following facts

```
"ansible_facts": {
        "facter_partitions": {
            "sda1": {
                "filesystem": "ext4",
                "label": "BOOT",
                "mount": "/boot",
                "size": "1048576",
                "uuid": "bfa6fa2e-2de5-48db-89ff-63df19e577bb"
            },
            "sda2": {
                "filesystem": "LVM2_member",
                "size": "82835456"
            }
        }
    },
```

I would like to get the `filesystem` of the device with the label `BOOT`

I tried to do it as like that

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - debug: msg={{ facter_partitions.values() | selectattr("label","search","BOOT")| map(attribute="filesystem") | list}}
```

But I get this error:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ facter_partitions.values() | selectattr(\"label\",\"search\",\"BOOT\") | map(attribute=\"filesystem\") | list }}): expected string or buffer"}
```

What is the proper way of getting that field? I do not expect the filter to return multiple values.

```
# ansible --version
ansible 2.4.2.0

# rpm -qa | grep jinja2
python-jinja2-2.7.2-2.el7.noarch

Red Hat 7.4
```

**Edit:**

The reason why this did not work is because I tried to filter on a field that was not defined on all the items. I first needed to filter for all the items that have "label" defined and then apply my filters.

```
{{ facter_partitions.values() | selectattr("label","defined") | selectattr("label","search","BOOT") | map(attribute="filesystem") | first }}
```

Comment: You are trying to use list operations on a dictionary.

Comment: even with the values() I get the same `{{ facter_partitions.values() | selectattr("label","search","BOOT")| list }}`

Comment: I clearly do something wrong as I still get `expected string or buffer`